# How to determine the executing environment platform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a library that is shared between an ASP.NET and a Winforms application, and there are 2 function implementations within it (should switch depending on a platform it is currently running on).

Unfortunately I cannot change the winforms app to isolate the logic from UI elements (this is how it's done now), so I need to be able to make a switch within the library code depending on environment.

**EDIT:**
Something like this

```
if(ASP.NET){
   myFuncSilent();
} else {
   myFuncWithDialogs();   
}

myFuncWithDialogs(){
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show('test');
}
myFuncSilent(){
   saveInLog('test');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "platform" and "environment"? Operating System, or something else?

Comment: @RufusL ASP.NET or windows forms

Comment: Can you please provide a short example of what you mean? Do you have control instances defined in library code?

Comment: @RufusL I have dialogs  - System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show() in winforms implementation

Comment: Got it. I don't know the short answer, but the long answer is to separate the logic from the UI. That code will not be very maintainable as it grows.

Comment: At the very least you should probably implement a logging class that you call for logging all messages, so that you don't have a bunch of duplicate methods and `if` statements scattered about.

Comment: @RufusL I agree that the long answer is the most appropriate way to go, but for now I'm just looking for a short solution because making changes in winforms app aren't feasible.